# communication between extensions developed for Google Chrome

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed two extentions (say extenstion A and extension B) for google chrome. Extension A uses Content-scripts.js A and extension B uses content-scripts.js B.

In content-scripts.js A, i have used localStorage.setItem("parameterVariable","hi");

In content-scripts.js B, i have used localStorage.getItem("parameterVariable"), which is suppose to return "hi", as extension A runs first and set the "paraneterVariable",and ectension B uses it. But it is returning NULL.

How to make the extension B's localStorage.getItem("parameterVariable") to return the value set by the extension B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would hazard to guess that extension are sand boxed from each other

Comment: so, wat would be the solution to make one extenstion pass variable to another extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [chrome.extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html) module.

Just make a request listener on one of the extensions and, in the other, send a request to the extension id of the first. More details about messaging [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).